# How to make even index values in array as keys and odd as values

Tags: php, arrays

I have data in an index array where even index values are keys and odd are values, I am trying to make them key value in new array, see my code below and suggest me.

```
Array
(
 [0] => firstName
 [1] => bob
 [2] => lastName
 [3] => alex
)
```

**Code**

```
    $k = array();
    $v = array();

    foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
        if ($key % 2 == 0) {
            $k[] = $value;
        }else{
            $v[] = $value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code will make two arrays of keys in $k and values in $v, which I guess is not what you want. So, $k will have ['firstName','lastName'] and $v will have ['bob','alex'].

Comment: yep but how to make them as ['firstname','bob'] and so on

Comment: Are you doing [array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) after?

Comment: ['firstname','bob'] is not Key=>Value, key value should be `$a['firstName'=>'bob','lastName'=>'alex']` - is this what you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using [`array_intersect_key`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) to select the odd-numbered values and then the even-numbered values (using [`range`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) to generate the list of key values), and then using [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to generate the output from those sets of values:

```
$a = [ 'firstname' , 'bob' , 'lastname' , 'alex' ];

$new = array_combine(
    array_intersect_key($a, array_flip(range(0, count($a) - 1, 2))),
    array_intersect_key($a, array_flip(range(1, count($a) - 1, 2)))
    );

print_r($new);
```

Output:

```
Array (
  [firstname] => bob
  [lastname] => alex 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/5IkF0)

Answer (score 4):

Alternative solution using a combination of `array_combine` and `array_filter`:

```
$joined = array_combine(
    array_filter($a, function($key) { return $key % 2 == 0; }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY),
    array_filter($a, function($key) { return $key % 2 != 0; }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY)
);
```

`$joined` will be:

```
Array
(
    [firstName] => bob
    [lastName] => alex
)
```

Of course, this will only work on an array with an even number of entries.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you mean, but Key=>Value can be achieved by doing this.

```
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    if ($key % 2 == 0) {
        $newArray[$value] = $a[$key+1];
    }
}

print_r($newArray);

// possible output of above code in the example given array would be something like 

Array ( ['firstName'=>'bob','lastName'=>'alex'] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a loop that skips the integer by two.

```
<?php
$old = array(
    'firstname',
    'bob',
    'lastName',
    'alex'
);

$new = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($old); $i += 2) {
    $new[$old[$i]] = $old[$i + 1];
}

print_r($new);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple for loop

```
$contents = [ 'firstname' , 'bob' , 'lastname' , 'alex' ];
$a = [];

for( $i = 0; $i<= count( $contents ) - 1; $i++ ){
    $a[ $contents[ $i ] ] = $contents[ $i + 1 ]; 
    $i++; //add another to skip every second
}

var_dump( $a );
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
  'firstname' => string 'bob' (length=3)
  'lastname' => string 'alex' (length=4)
```